# Logstash traverse s3 directory tree for logs

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, elasticsearch, logstash

We have about four years worth of our logs stored on **Amazon S3** in a bucket in the format of

```
BUCKET/path/logs/blah/YEARMONTHDAYHOUR/server1.log
BUCKET/path/logs/blah/YEARMONTHDAYHOUR/server2.log
BUCKET/path/logs/blah/YEARMONTHDAYHOUR/server3.log
```

etc.

And our goal is to use this data to backfill and index logs going forward using Logstash, so I was wondering if there was a way of telling the s3 input plugin to search for all logs within folders within a specified prefix, similar to:

```
"path" => "/path/logs/blah/**/*.log
```

If there isn't a way to do that with the `s3 plugin`, have any of you solved a similar problem? 
Ideal would be being able background the process and keep it is a close to real time as possible (Meaning I'd like to avoid something where I have to manually copy logs to an outside location and run the script to update the index)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
The solution I've found is the following.

1. Mount the S3 bucket as a removable drive in the local file system.
2. Use [file](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) input plugin to index target log files.

Using this approach neither manual copying nor script running is required. The indexing is performed on background.

There are several S3 client applications that help to mount S3 bucket as local drive (for example [TntDrive](http://tntdrive.com/)). However all of them are commercial softwares. I didn't find any free application so far.

My operating system is Windows 7 and I used TntDrive to mount S3 bucket to my local file system.